# Excel VBA: nested dictionary issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to create a nested dictionary, assign it to a variable, overwrite one of the inner values, and then assign it to another variable without the original variable's value getting changed, which I do not want. For example, see the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()

  Dim d_outer As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set d_outer = New Scripting.Dictionary

  Dim d_inner As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set d_inner = New Scripting.Dictionary

  Call d_inner.Add("key", "foo")

  Call d_outer.Add("first attempt", d_inner)

  ' Cannot use "Add", since key already exists, must use Item()
  d_inner.Item("key") = "bar"

  Call d_outer.Add("second attempt", d_inner)

  ' Print all values.
  Dim v_outer As Variant
  Dim v_inner As Variant
  For Each v_outer In d_outer.Keys()
    For Each v_inner In d_outer(v_outer).Keys()
      Debug.Print "(" & v_outer & ", " & v_inner & "): '" & d_outer(v_outer)(v_inner) & "'"
    Next v_inner
  Next v_outer
End Sub
```

This produces the following output:

```
(first attempt, key): 'bar'
(second attempt, key): 'bar'
```

The first attempt's value should be `foo`. Why is it getting changed to `bar`? How do I fix this? Do I need to create a new dictionary that's an exact copy of d_inner every time I want to change only one of the values? If so, is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: This line: `d_inner.Item("key") = "bar"` changes `first attempt` to `bar`

Comment: Yes, I know that. But since we've already called the Add() method on the previous line for the "first attempt" key with the original (correct) value, shouldn't that not matter for that key?

Comment: Explained in my answer below. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first collection you have created a reference to an object rather than placing a value in there (for example). So as you change the inner collection it is updated in the initial outer collection.

You need to create a `New` object to put into the second collection. Like this:

```
  ' Cannot use "Add", since key already exists, must use Item()      
   Set d_inner = New Scripting.Dictionary
   Call d_inner.Add("key", "bar")
```

Gives:

```
(first attempt, key): 'foo'
(second attempt, key): 'bar'
```

Depending on what you are trying to achieve here, you might find that classes are more flexible with these kinds of tasks