# VBA: Is nested dictionary a good solution for this?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with colored cells.  I was trying to build a VBA script that can return the row number(s) that match the pre-selected cell colors.  However the color is "column-specific", which means it should only match the color in the same column as the selected cells.

For example, in the screenshot attached, pre-selected cells are A3(blue) and B4(red).

[image: Example]

The desired return is: 1, 3, 4, 5.  It should not return 2 because even though B2 is in blue color, but there's no blue color cell selected in column B.

What is the best data structure to solve this problem?

Here are my thoughts:

1) In a single column, multiple cells may be selected.  Duplicated colors may exist.  I was thinking of using a Colors dictionary to store the pre-selected color in the column.

2) Since colors are "column-specific", I was thinking of using a Columns dictionary to track the columns that has pre-selected cells.  Use column number as key, and Colors(dictionary) as value.

3) My code is as below:

```
Dim objSelection As Range
Dim objSelectionArea As Range
Dim objCell As Range
Dim c, r As Long
Dim Columns As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim Colors As New Scripting.Dictionary

' Get the current selection
Set objSelection = Application.Selection

' Walk through the areas
For Each objSelectionArea In objSelection.Areas

    ' Walk through the cells in an area
    For Each objCell In objSelectionArea
        c = objCell.Column
        r = objCell.Row
        cellColor = objCell.Interior.Color

        ' If this is a new column add it to dictionary. Also add color.
        If Not Columns.Exists(c) Then
            ' Put cell color into color dictionary as key
            Colors.Add cellColor, r
            ' Put color dictionary into column dictionary
            Columns.Add c, Colors
        ' if colomn already in dictionary, just do the color part
        ElseIf Not Columns(c).Exists(cellColor) Then
            Columns(c).Add cellColor, r
        End If
    Next

Next

' Walk through each columns that has selected cells
For Each c in Columns.Keys
    ' Walk through each cells in this column
    For r = 1 to MaxRow' Assuming MaxRow is the last row number of the table

        ' If the cell color in the the column-specific RefColor dictionary
        If Columns(c).Exists(Cells(r, c).Interior.Color) Then
        ' Do something here to indicate row r is one of the matches
        End If

    Next

Next
```

The problem of this nested dictionary is - the Colors dictionary is not "column-specific"(even though I nested it in a 'Columns' dictionary.  When I store colors into Colors, it's like adding colors into a global/single dictionary.  So the outcome does not meet business requirement.

Is nested dictionary the best data structure for this problem?  Or shall I use a different data structure?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: [Excel VBA: nested dictionary issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489252/excel-vba-nested-dictionary-issue)

I'm a newbie to VBA so I made a mistake in the original code.

I should create a new inner dictionary whenever adding a new key to the outer dictionary.

So instead of:

```
Dim Colors As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

I should have done:

```
Dim Colors As Scripting.Dictionary
```

Then, whenever adding a new key to the outer dictionary, I should do:

```
Set Colors = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: This is what Mistella mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I think the nested dictionaries could work; although you would have to make a few changes to make the colors dictionary truly column specific.

Note my changes in your code below:

- Did not explicitly declare a single Colors dictionary. Declaring specific colors dictionary meant:

  - Sub/Function level variable (apparent Global dictionary behavior)
  - Adding to Columns dictionary, simply added additional references to existing Colors Dictionary
  - Can reference Colors dictionary by variable name
- Instead, when the cell is in a new column, add a new dictionary into the Columns dictionary. This means:

  - Each dictionary "added" to the columns dictionary is unique.
  - Column-level variable; instead of global
  - Can not refer to dictionary by name; only by reference to item/key connection from the Columns dictionary
  - Code to add color to color dictionary(s) becomes identical between if column exists or if it does not (thus, the slight change in the logic block)
- `Dim c As Variant`: This is what your code was doing implicitly. For VBA variables, each variable needs to be declared separately, or it defaults to Variant

  - If `c` is declared as long, a different Variant variable will need to be declared for looping through the dictionary keys.

**Note:**
*The line `Columns(c).Add cellColor, r` adds the cell color as a key in the dictionary and the row as the item. This means that if that color already exists in that dictionary, the item will be overwritten with the new row value. Looking at your code, that **shouldn't** be an issue (selecting `r` as row value from looping through row numbers), but I thought I should mention this just in case you were planning on preserving the row values of the originally selected cells.*

---

```
Dim objSelection As Range
Dim objSelectionArea As Range
Dim objCell As Range
Dim c As Variant 'Made implied declaration explicit. Needs to be variant or the "for each c" loop fails
Dim r As Long
Dim Columns As New Scripting.Dictionary

' Get the current selection
Set objSelection = Application.Selection

' Walk through the areas
For Each objSelectionArea In objSelection.Areas

    ' Walk through the cells in an area
    For Each objCell In objSelectionArea
        c = objCell.Column
        r = objCell.Row
        cellColor = objCell.Interior.Color

        ' If this is a new column add it to dictionary. Also add color.
        ' Simplified If-End If....
        If Not Columns.Exists(c) Then
            ' Put color dictionary into column dictionary
            Columns.Add c, New Scripting.Dictionary ' Creates new dictionary for each column
        End If

        ' Put cell color into color dictionary as key
        Columns(c).Add cellColor, r
    Next

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an efficient data structure

This uses nested dictionaries of colors, based on columns

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetColColorsBasedOnSelectedRows()
    Dim ur As Range, c As Long, r As Long, rCnt As Long, cCnt As Long, sel As Range
    Dim d As Dictionary, dColors As Dictionary, cc As Long, res As String, sCell As Range

    Set ur = Sheet1.UsedRange
    rCnt = ur.Rows.Count
    cCnt = ur.Columns.Count
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For c = 1 To cCnt   'Get all colors in all used range, by columns
        Set dColors = New Scripting.Dictionary
        For r = 1 To rCnt
            cc = ur(r, c).Interior.Color
            If InStr(1, dColors(cc), r & ", ") = 0 Then
                dColors(cc) = dColors(cc) & r & ", "
            End If
        Next
        Set d(c) = dColors
    Next
    Dim msg As String, shown As Dictionary
    Set shown = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each sel In Application.Selection.Areas
        For Each sCell In sel.Cells
            If Not shown.Exists(sCell.Column & "-" & sCell.Interior.Color) Then
                msg = msg & sCell.Address(0, 0) & ", "
                res = res & d(sCell.Column)(sCell.Interior.Color)
                shown(sCell.Column & "-" & sCell.Interior.Color) = 0
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Debug.Print "Selected cells: " & Left(msg, Len(msg) - 2)
    Debug.Print "Row colors:     " & Left(res, Len(res) - 2) & vbCrLf
    ShowAllItems d
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub ShowAllItems(ByRef d As Dictionary)

    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, i As Long, m As String

    For Each x In d
        i = i + 1
        For Each y In d(x)
          m = d(x)(y)
          Debug.Print "Column: " & i & ", Color: " & y & ", Rows: " & Left(m, Len(m) - 2)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Result

```
Selected cells: A3, B4, C2, D1, D7
Row colors:     1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5, 7

Column: 1, Color: 16772300,   Rows: 1, 3
Column: 1, Color: 6684672,    Rows: 2
Column: 1, Color: 16777215,   Rows: 4, 5, 6
Column: 1, Color: 192,        Rows: 7
Column: 2, Color: 16777215,   Rows: 1, 3, 6
Column: 2, Color: 16772300,   Rows: 2
Column: 2, Color: 192,        Rows: 4, 5
Column: 2, Color: 6684672,    Rows: 7
Column: 3, Color: 16777215,   Rows: 1, 3, 4, 7
Column: 3, Color: 6684672,    Rows: 2
Column: 3, Color: 16772300,   Rows: 5
Column: 3, Color: 192,        Rows: 6
Column: 4, Color: 192,        Rows: 1, 6
Column: 4, Color: 16777215,   Rows: 2
Column: 4, Color: 6684672,    Rows: 3, 5, 7
Column: 4, Color: 16772300,   Rows: 4
```

---

Sheet1

[image: Sheet1]